# Bash script to install AWS CLI tools

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am writing a bash script that will automatically install and configure AWS CLI tools. I am able to install AWS CLI tools but unable to configure it.

My script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
./awscli-bundle/install -h

aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP   ## unable to provide this data
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: xbdwsdADDS/ssfsfa/afzfASADQASAd   ## unable to provide this data
Default region name [None]: us-west-2   ## unable to provide this data
Default output format [None]: json   ## unable to provide this data
```

I wish to do the configuration using this script too. I wish that I can provide these credentials via script so that it prevents manual entry. How can this be done?

Comment: If you're looking to run this on instances you launch, consider using [IAM Roles for EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) instead of embedding your credentials. The instance takes care of issuing temporary credentials and rotating them, you just need to specify the IAM role when you launch the instance. You will still need to install the actual tools though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a configuration file rather than the `aws configure` command. Create a file called `~/.aws/config` that looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
region=us-west-2
output=json
```

More info [in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).

Comment: Other than that, you can also set the credentials, region and output as environment variables or cli arguments.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Comment: I am unable to find directory  ~/.aws/

Comment: you will need to create the directory ~/.aws and inside it the file 'config'

Answer (score 2):

the best practice is to install the **awscli** utility by BASH and copy the file from your own specified location of 2 files

without hitting

```
#aws configure
```

command these files will not get created, you can copy and paste the files using bash script and get all the execution done

```
~/.aws/credintials
~/.aws/config
```

where credentials contains

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
aws_secret_access_key=xbdwsdADDS/ssfsfa/afzfASADQASAd
```

and config file contains

```
[default]
output=json
region=us-west-2
```

This will help you to keep the keys at one place and you can also push the same for your execution for any CMT tool as well like Ansible.

Answer (score 2):

you additionally configure this from the command line which will create the configuration file

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key xbdwsdADDS/ssfsfa/afzfASADQASAd
aws configure set default.region eu-west-1
```