# Python - Dynamic variable in Redshift SQL Query

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm developing in a python environment and I want to call an sql query using `psycopg2`

Lets say I have the following UNLOAD command in an .sql file:

```
UNLOAD 
(
'
Some SQL Query
'
)
TO 's3://%PATH%'
...
```

In the sql file the `%PATH%` should be explicit like: `'folder1/folder3/file_name'`.

But I want the python program to set this `%PATH%` in runtime. which means that the .sql file containts something like `%PATH%` and will be set only in runtime.

Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: why not just concat the query using the static part as string and the filename from the external variable? then you're able to assign this variable from command line parameter

Comment: I would hope for a more structured solution. For when I open and read the sql file I just write something like '%PATH% = python_var' and its over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply specify a [replacement field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) in your SQL file, and the use a format command.

Create your file like this

```
UNLOAD ('Some SQL Query')
TO 's3://{bucket}/{key}'
```

And use this file in python like

```
template = open('file1.sql', 'r').read()
query = template.format(bucket='mybucket', key='folder/file.csv')
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Alas I've already implemented the other solution. But when I refactor I will certainly change it to the "replacement field" solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing it this way will give you a tough time.

The best way to do is to dump the file at a static location:

```
UNLOAD 
(
'
Some SQL Query
'
)
TO 's3://path/to/static/s3_bucket'
...
```

and then use (via a shellscript / or opt for a suitable command for any other script)

`aws s3 mv $source $destination`

Here, you may pass any value for  `$destination` which can be easily populated during run-time.

> In short, you've dumped the file in s3 at a fixed location (using
>   UNLOAD) and moved it to the location of your choice or a location
>   populated at run time (using aws s3 mv...)

Comment: How exactly do I run `aws s3 mv $source $destination` from python ?

Comment: Install an aws cli on your machine. You can find some help at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536583/bash-script-to-install-aws-cli-tools
This'll help you to work with your s3 buckets from cli.

Comment: Well I took your idea, to just copy and delete. used boto3 though.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to set up the UNLOAD path dynamically at runtime, however you could put your SQL statement in a something like a shell/python script where you can create variables with the path you'd like and then pass them into the query.

[This](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/UnloadCopyUtility/redshift-unload-copy.py) UNLOAD utility by AWS will get you started if you decide to go with a python script.